# Mostrar imágenes de base de datos con PHP

Tags: php, java, android, mysql, mysqli

Que tal, lo que quiero es mostrar imágenes que tengo almacenadas en una base de datos en MySQL, en una columna esta la ruta de las imágenes y las imágenes en una carpeta, esto con PHP para después utilizarlas en android, pero primero quiero visualizar las imágenes utilizando este código, a pesar de no marcar errores no muestra las imágenes, espero me puedan ayudar por favor.

La imagen se guarda en la base como:

```
http://127.0.1.1/uap/uploads/124.jpg
```

el 124 es el numero de id

PHP modificado:

```
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","reg"); 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM reportes2";
$sth = $db->query($sql);
$result=mysqli_fetch_array($sth);
$ruta = '<img src = http://127.0.1.1/uap/uploads/';
$ruta.=$result['url'];
$ruta.='">';
echo $ruta;
echo '<img src="data:url/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $result['url'] 
).'"/>';
?>
```

PHP:

```
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","reg"); 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM reportes2";
$sth = $db->query($sql);
$result=mysqli_fetch_array($sth);
echo '<img src="data:url/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $result['url'] ).'"/>';
?>
```

PHP para almacenar imagenes:

```
<?php

// Import db file.
require_once 'dbDetails.php';

// Upload folder.
$upload_path = 'uploads/';

// Get the server ip.
$server_ip = gethostbyname(gethostname());

// Create upload url.
$upload_url = 'http://' . $server_ip . '/userapp/' . $upload_path;

//response array 
$response = array();

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
.
.
.
```

Comment: Si tu imagen está en una carpeta y en la base de datos tienes un campo que identifique la imagen y la extensión por ejemplo, puedes construir la ruta de la imagen y ponerla en un src. Por ejemplo: `$ruta='<img src="http://www.tu-dominio.com/uploads/';` Luego completas con el dato dinámico: `$ruta.=$result['url'];` Finalmente cierras el elemento: `$ruta.='">';`  y ahora muestras la imagen: `echo $ruta;`

Comment: He modificado el PHP con su comentario y no muestra error pero sigue sin mostrar las imagenes @A.Cedano, editare con el PHP modificado esperando me pueda seguir ayudando..

Comment: Te falta la comilla: `<img src ="http://127.0.1.1/uap/uploads/'`  y no uses espacios, debe ir todo junto.  Luego, lo de `uap` no sé que es... Tienes que probar si la imagen se abre poniendo en el navegador esto: `http://127.0.1.1/uap/uploads/124.jpg`  o esto: `http://127.0.1.1/uploads/124.jpg` para ver cuál de las dos es la forma correcta de hacerlo. Luego, debes decir si esperas varias filas en la consulta SQL, porque de ser así deberás ir recorriendo los resultados dentro de un `while`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si :

- Todas las imágenes se encuentran en esta carpeta: `uap/uploads`
- En la columna `url` de la base de datos tienes datos como estos: `124.jpg`

Entonces puedes proceder así:

Dado que la parte primera nunca cambia, puedes definir una variable fuera del bucle, y dentro agregarle los valores dinámicos.

Luego en el bucle, necesitas un array asociativo, no estoy seguro que `fecht_array` lo cree por defecto, así que mejor le decimos el tipo de array que queremos.

El código sería así más o menos:

```
$ruta = '<img src="http://127.0.1.1/uap/uploads/';
$result=$db->query($sql);

while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    /*Concatenamos el valor fijo a cada valor en la columna url*/
    $img_url=$ruta.$row['url'];

    /*Completamos la cadena*/
    $img_url.='">';

    /*Imprimimos ESTA imagen*/
    echo $img_url;
}
```

Para que funcione debes asegurarte que:

- La conexión a la base de datos funciona y que la consulta está arrojando datos
- Al escribir URLs como esta en el navegador `http://127.0.1.1/uap/uploads/124.jpg` puedes en efecto ver una imagen.

Comment: uap es el nombre de la base de datos, ya hice las pruebas que me dijo, y si se conecta pero no muestra la imagen, en vez de eso muestra la leyenda de '¡Objeto no localizado!', 'Error 404

127.0.1.1
Apache/2.4.18 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2e PHP/7.0.8'

Comment: @Armando ¿Pero las imágenes existen realmente en esa carpeta ? ¿Las ves poniendo la URL a mano?

Comment: Si, las carpetas ahí están, el nombre de la imagen es solo su id, "14.jpg" hay unas que su extencion es diferente pero le cambiaba a .jpeg, png, etc. lo intente hacer de forma local y usando el servidor pero no tengo respuesta, por ejemplo de forma local tengo una ruta de una imagen guardada como: http://192.168.1.65/registrovallarta2/uploads/28.jpg en el navegador escribía  http://192.168.1.65/registrovallarta2/uploads/28.jpg mi duda es que mi ip de la maquina actual no es la 192.168.1.65 tendrá algo que ver?